# how to get macro variable to evaluate math?

Tags: sas

I have the following sas marco snippet:

```
%macro processLink(uuid=, name=, cluster_external_ipaddress=);

 %let unix_starttime = 1000000*(&starttime - '01JAN1970:00:00'dt);
 %let unix_endtime = 1000000*(&endtime - '01JAN1970:00:00'dt);
...
```

when this runs it just creates the variable as a string ie

=1000000*(dhms(today()-1,0,0,0) - '01JAN1970:00:00'dt)

instead of the unix timestamp in usecs.

using unix_starttime = 1000000*(&starttime - '01JAN1970:00:00'dt); outside the macro in a data step works

do i need a *null* datastep in the macro for this to work as intended ?

Thanks

Comment: Don't get me started about SAS Marco

Comment: Where do the values for STARTTIME and ENDTIME macro variables come from? What do they look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if you want to work with DATA you are better off using SAS code and not MACRO code.  You can use CALL SYMPUTX() to generate a macro variable if you need it later.

```
data _null_;
  call symputx('unix_starttime',1000000*(&starttime - '01JAN1970:00:00'dt));
  ...
run;
```

You can use %eval() to do simple integer arithmetic and comparisons. If you need to use floating point numbers (or date/time/datetime literals) then you need to use %sysevalf().

```
 %let unix_starttime=%sysevalf(1000000*(&starttime - '01JAN1970:00:00'dt));
```

Comment: Thanks, all working now with the additional help from @J_Lard and using %sysfunc

Answer (score 1):

In general, anything after a `%let` statement is treated as pure text.  However, there are functions available to wrap around the text which tell SAS to perform a mathematical operation.

These are `%eval`, used for integer calculations, or `%sysevalf` where calculations involving decimals are required.

So you could put `%let unix_starttime = %eval(1000000*(&starttime - '01JAN1970:00:00'dt));`

It's not applicable here, but if you ever need to include a function in a `%let` statement, then precede the function name with `%sysfunc`

Comment: I still get an error with the %eval added ( is it the & of the datetime text causing the issue?  :  - %let unix_starttime = %eval(1000000*(&starttime - '01JAN1970:00:00'dt));
ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required. The condition was: 
       1000000*(dhms(today()-1,0,0,0) - '01JAN1970:00:00'dt)

Comment: @DwayneDibbley You need to put `%sysfunc` around your functions when you create the `&starttime` macro variable. `%sysfunc(dhms(%sysfunc(today())-1,0,0,0)`.

Comment: You need to use %SYSEVALF() if you want it to recognize a date literal.